# Excel: External dynamic referencing

Tags: excel, dynamic, reference

I've tried following some of the posts here on stackoverflow with regards to dynamic referencing but I'm struggling to implement it into my sheet.

I want to make this reference dynamic:

```
=INDIRECT("'[SA report Aut 2021.xlsx]Graphs Term Progress'!$B$9")
```

To something like this:

```
=INDIRECT("'[SA report " & Home!D4 & " " & Home!D6 & ".xlsx]Graphs Term Progress'!$B$9")
```

I'm I on the right tree or barking up the wrong track?

Thanx for reading,
Sam

Comment: INDIRECT will not work when the source workbook is closed, but other than that the general syntax looks fine.

Comment: Yeah, I have the book open but it doesn't seem to be playing ball. I'll do some more tinkering. Thanx for getting back to me so quickly.

Comment: Sorry - just spotted you're not quite right: `=INDIRECT("'[SA report " & Home!D4 & " " & Home!D6 & ".xlsx]Graphs Term Progress'!$B$9")`

Comment: Just noticed it myself. Updated. Thanx again.

Comment: Must have been something I typed. I wrote it out again and it works.

Comment: That should work then assuming those cells actually contain the correct values.